The Zentralblatt asked me to review a worthless paper, what to do?
I am an amateur mathematician who at age 64 finally became published in January.  As a result, review requests started coming in.
The first two were from two different journals.  Both papers were well within my subject area so I accepted.  I spent a bunch of time carefully reviewing each and gave the authors extensive feedback (this was explicitly acknowledged in both papers).  After multiple revisions (in each case), I recommended both papers be published.
The third request was from zbMath about a month ago.  Not familiar enough with the subject, I declined.
The fourth request was from zbMath several days ago.  I could tell right away this paper would be easy to understand, so I accepted.
When I looked closer however, I discovered it's too easy to understand!  It's like a grade school homework assignment!  It has no research value whatsoever.  It mystifies me how it ever made it into a Springer publication (it's a chapter in the 2023 book Advances in Topology and Their Interdisciplinary Applications).
Should I contact zbMath to express my opinion it doesn't deserve a review, or instead just move forward and write a very scathing one?  I'm leaning towards the latter option because it seems like a golden opportunity: when will I ever see a paper this bad again?

Somewhat relevant is How to write a good MathSciNet review? (mathoverflow). See also "MR Folklore: Unflattering Reviews" on p. 332 of Chinese Acrobatics, an Old-Time Brewery, and the “Much Needed Gap”: The Life of Mathematical Reviews by Allyn Jackson [Notices of the American Mathematical Society 44 #3, March 1997, pp. 330-337].

I skimmed the book's table of contents and none of the titles suggest "grade school homework". Not all papers make a major contribution: the vast majority of papers make small incremental advancements in the field. Publications such as reviews, surveys, tutorials and opinion papers don't make any advancement and present a topic in an easy-to-understand manner. As an amateur, it sounds like your inexperience, and "finally becoming published" is getting to your head and causing unrealistic expectations.

Although https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24325/ is about Math Reviews rather than Zentralblatt, it might still be useful here.

@user71659 The title is a con job. For example "T_0" appears in it (and several theorems) without ever being used once in a proof.

There is far far too much mathematical detail here. Please make this a generalizable question

I wonder why you assume that chapters in Springer books undergo a peer review process? This is not my general experience.

@JFabianMeier if the paper didn't undergo a peer review process then the authors thanking the "anonymous reviewers for their useful comments" was a lie (I wouldn't put it past them), but the book does name an editor (Santanu Acharjee) who presumably doesn't just rubber stamp.  I wasn't even aware collections like this exist.  I thought they were always from conferences.

Maybe the point of the chapter was not the math, but the "Interdisciplinary Application" of it.

@mathematrucker I know conferences from my personal experience in which every speaker was allowed to publish something in the resulting Springer book. There may be some kind of "review" by the editors and their staff in which they suggest improvements, but without the possibility to reject the paper.

In looking at the math detail you gave in an earlier edit (an edit I only just now realized existed), maybe you could include something like the following: It is unclear how the results apply to [insert whatever other subject the results are supposed to have a connection with], but the theorem statements could usefully serve as "prove or give a counterexample" exercises early in a general topology course in which students are also asked to identify any unnecessary assumptions (if they exist) in those cases where the theorem statements are true.

@GEdgar thanks, I know who you are and appreciate your feedback.  I thought of that possibility and read some of Koblitz's work for guidance.  The math in this paper is at least math, unlike what the 80s NAS controversy was about, but the inferiority of this content looks very similar to me.

@DaveLRenfro yes the theorems do have that one redeeming quality.  Errors in textbooks can make good exercises to spot too.  My being asked to review such a paper has presented me with a sort of exercise that I hope to learn from.  The reason I'm devoting so much time to it is I like to do things right.

with a sort of exercise that I hope to learn from --- This is the case for many papers I have by someone whose papers I once described as follows: [X]'s papers tend to be short, not very deep, often appear in fairly obscure journals, are quite weak in informing the reader of related work, and tend to be overly pedantic. Nonetheless, many of them in my opinion would serve quite well as advanced undergraduate or beginning graduate student seminar topics. Excerpt from this 20 Sep 2000 sci.math post.

@DaveLRenfro Abian's Wikipedia page mentions another eccentricity: he favored destroying the Moon.  I'd never heard of this idea before.  The page says he firmly believed it would end natural disasters.  Sort of reminds me of Linus Pauling and vitamin C.

Regarding Abian and the moon, I first heard about this from a 24 June 1991 article, which I cited and gave an excerpt from in the 20 September 2000 sci.math post I cited in my previous comment. In fact, that sci.math thread was started by Erland Gadde who heard Abian's name mentioned on TV in connection with the moon, and Erland Gadde wondered if this is the same person who had been a somewhat regular sci.math poster (yes). FYI, this 28 July 1999 sci.math post begins a thread where Abian's death was announced.

Zentralblatt as you know is a repository of short reviews used as a way to find articles. As a mathematician, you are supposed to scan the Zentralblatt (or reviews) to identify papers in your field. Not reviewing because of bad quality is not an option. If you are sure that this is not a good paper, you are supposed to tell, so that no-one starts spending money on access to the paper.
I assume that you have made sure that you are not overlooking something.
Reviews along the lines: "No new results are presented." have been published before. It happens. My Ph.D. advisor had to review a paper that was based on an elementary misunderstanding and got by the reviewer. The paper was completely false. He struggled with what to do until a visitor showed him a review along the lines: "All the definitions are well known. All results that are not trivial are false." My advisor ended up sending a warning to the author who was a young Mathematician just starting out and wrote a review that said that unfortunately, the results are wrong and why.
You can of course ask the Zentralblatt to check your review, but you should not fudge the issue. The mistake was made by the editor of the collection, not by you. You just state that the contents are worthless because of the reasons in a succinct manner.

Perhaps a less inflammatory word than "worthless" could be used.

You can write a negative review without being unkind.

I have often had to write highly negative reviews and I try to give them as much care as positive ones. Try to stick to objective language and to explain clearly what is wrong (are the results trivial or are they unoriginal or are they false, and if so why?)

Conversely to Deee's excellent comment, if you can't/won't, or don't know how to write a negative review without being unkind (always consider your own reaction to receiving a review that you write, as if it were from someone else), it would be best, perhaps, to ask for advice from a colleague or advisor, however you stated you are an amateur?

@ScottSeidman Stick with facts for "bad news" is a good idea. "Worthless" can be seen as subjective, but the suggested phrase "All the definitions are well known. All results that are not trivial are false." is factual. More factual details can be provided that isn't just "I feel it is so".

Of course, we all write negative reviews now and again.  When I do (for papers -- grants are another story), the message, as clearly as I can give it, goes into "confidential to editor".  For every other field, my habit is to use language that I would use when talking face-to-face to the authors.

@CGCampbell yes I am an amateur.  My goal is to write a professional-looking review.  Here is a possible first sentence: "Do a few applications of the equation $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$
justify $15$ references on the inclusion-exclusion principle and adding it to the title?"

IMO the best way to write a scathing review is to just stick to the facts. A author that submits a paper this trivial may just misunderstand your rhetorical question as a genuine one, or as snarky, neither of which is what you want. Perhaps try: equations (1), (2), .. are trivial and known since antiquity (insert reference to Archimedes).

@Johan: And now i'm wondering how to cite prehistoric sources :D Include a scan of the stone tablet ?

@Johan snarky isn't necessarily bad, especially given my relative freedom as an amateur.  I plan to read some of Neal Koblitz's work for guidance on how to proceed.  I've never met him but I lived next door to him in Seattle during the summer of 1982 (one of my housemates, a "get to know the neighbors" kind of guy, was acquainted with him).

As a rule of thumb, I recommend to write the paper as if you will later meet the author in person, and in such a way that you can defend this in their face.
